# Clear form after submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am submitting a form - and adding the contents to an array, however whenever the item is added to the array, it is still bound to the form.

I would like to add the item, clear the form. Something like jquery's reset();

Here's my template:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-controller="ResourceController">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Name</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h3>Description</h3>
    </div>
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" ng-repeat="item in resources">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ item.name }}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-7">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ item.description }}"/>
        </div>
    </form>
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" name="addResourceForm" ng-submit="addResource()">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="name" placeholder="Name"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-7">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" ng-model="description" placeholder="Description"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-1">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And my controller:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('event-resources', []);
    app.controller('ResourceController', function($scope){
        $scope.addResource = function(){
            $scope.resources.push(this);
        }

        var defaultForm = {
            name : '',
            description: ''
        };

        $scope.resources = [
         {
            name: 'Beer',
            description: 'Kokanee'
         },
         {
            name: 'Pucks',
            description: 'Black Round Things'
         }
       ]
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `angular.copy()` to copy the item data to the resources array, and then you can safely clear the item data. The `angular.copy()` makes a deep copy of the object, which is what you want.

---

Alternately, here is a simpler method, which doesn't use any extra method calls:

```
$scope.addResource = function() {
  $scope.resources.push({
    name: $scope.name,      // recreate object manually (cheap for simple objects)
    description: $scope.description
  });
  $scope.name = "";         // clear the values.
  $scope.description = "";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.addResource = function(){
            $scope.resources.push(angular.copy(this));
            $scope.name="";
            $scope.description=""
        }
```

Push the copy to the resources array and change name and description back to ""